# Getting text in body as string in one cell

Tags: xpath, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I am trying to get via `IMPORTXML` all text that is on a page as string in one cell.

For example, when opening the following [website](http://www.ediktsdatei.justiz.gv.at/edikte/ku/kuedi7.nsf/0/03e360bfbf4e7439c125804b002c26a7!OpenDocument) I would like to get all that is in the body tag.

I tried the following: `=transpose(IMPORTXML(A3,"/html/body/text()"))`

Below you can find my example spreadsheet with 5 urls:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LblNn8mGjSr5Tn5R5yZibXXq2w7DaHxDqKwmaD66cAQ/edit?usp=sharing

My problem is that I do not get any result back.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 3 really easy ways to do this  (technically more but we wont get carried away), the only difference in the variations are how they are formatted in the end:

1 - If you want to preserve the full formatting, or have similar line breaks you can wrap you function in `JOIN` and use `CHAR(10)` as your delimiter, which is the equivalent of a hard return or new line:

```
=join(char(10),IMPORTXML(A3,"//body"))
```

[image]

2 - You can do the same function but only join with a space instead of a full new line:

```
=join(" ",IMPORTXML(A3,"//body"))
```

[image]

3- Or if the goal is actually just to save the data with as little additional whitespace and new lines you can use both concatenate and regexreplace to replace exisiting new lines:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(CONCATENATE(IMPORTXML(A3,"//body")),"\n","")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
=ArrayFormula( CONCATENATE(IMPORThtml(A3,"table",2) & CHAR(10) ) )
```